# CakePHP3: Check if model exists

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

I have a search engine which calls a Cakephp action and receives which model the engine should search in eg. "Projects". The variable is called `$data_type`;

Right now I use this to check if the model exists:

```
// Check if Table really exists
    if(!TableRegistry::get($data_type)){

        // Send error response to view
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'error' => 'Data type does not exist'
        ];
        $this->set('response', $response);
        return;
    }
```

I'm not sure I'm doing it the right or the safest way to check if a model exists, because I don't know if the `TableRegistry::get()` function is vulnerable to SQL injection behind the scenes.

I also found that inputing an empty string to the get() function doesn't need in a false result??? Is there a safe solution I can implement that will solve my problem?

Comment: I think you should first clarify the terms that you're using. When you're saying "_check if a table exists_", are you referring to database tables, or to your applications table classes? The latter don't neccesarily need to exist.

Comment: I changed it now to the model :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `TableRegistry::get()` is not safe to use with user input

First things first. It's probably rather complicated to inject dangerous SQL via `TableRegistry::get()`, but not impossible, as the alias passed in the first argument will be used as the database table name in case an auto/generic-table instance is created. However the schema lookup will most likely fail before anything else, also the name will be subject to inflection, specifically underscore and lowercase inflection, so an injection attempt like

```
Foo; DELETE * FROM Bar;
```

would end up as:

```
foo;d_e_l_e_t_e*f_r_o_m_bar;
```

This would break things as it's invalid SQL, but it won't cause further harm. The bottom line however is that **`TableRegistry::get()` cannot be regarded as safe to use with user input!**

### The class of the returned instance indicates a table class' existence

`TableRegistry::get()` looks up and instantiates possible existing table classes for the given alias, and if that fails, it will create a so called auto/generic-table, which is an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table` instead of an instance of a concrete subclass thereof.

So you could check the return value against `\Cake\ORM\Table` to figure whether you've retrieved an instance of an actual existing table class:

```
$table = TableRegistry::get($data_type);
if (get_class($table) === \Cake\ORM\Table::class) {
    // not an existing table class
    // ...
}
```

### Use a whitelist

That being said, unless you're working on some kind of administration tool that explicitly needs to be able to access to all tables, the proper thing do would be to use some sort of whitelisting, as having users arbitrarily look up any tables they want **could be a security risk**:

```
$whitelist = [
    'Projects',
    '...'
];

if (in_array($data_type, $whitelist, true) !== true) {
    // not in the whitelist, access prohibited
    // ...
}
```

Ideally you'd go even further and apply similar restrictions to the columns that can be looked up.

You may want to checkout **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#search** for some ready made search plugins.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will go with the whitelist method. In the end i dont have that many tables that should allow searches in them.